# How to kill Windows service process stuck at starting?

Tags: windows, service, process, terminate, kill-process

I have a problem with one service which stuck at starting stage when I try to start such service, and I am not able to terminate such process. I know that restart is a solution, but server can't be restart couple times everyday, also any additional software like Process Explorer is not allowed to be installed and used.

So far I tried to use below solution (all commands were executed as admin):

```
taskkill /f /pid 7788
ERROR: The process with PID 7788 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

C:\Windows\system32>wmic
wmic:root\cli>process where name="ProcesName.exe" delete
Delete '\\xxxxx\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle="7788"' (Y/N/?)? y
Deleting instance \\xxxxx\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle="7788"
ERROR:
Description = Access denied
wmic:root\cli>


C:\Windows\system32>wmic
wmic:root\cli>process where name="ProcesName.exe" call terminate
Execute (\\xxxxx\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle="7788")->terminate() (Y/N/?)? y
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 2;
};

wmic:root\cli>


C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /IM "ProcessName.exe" /T /F
ERROR: The process with PID 7788 (child process of PID 680) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

C:\Windows\system32>tasklist | findstr 680
services.exe                   680 Services                   0      9 084 K
java.exe                      5832 Services                   0    443 680 K
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Run PowerShell as an administrator

2- Enter: `Get-Service`
like this pic
[After enter Get-Service command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kaRS.png)

3- Enter: `Stop-Service -Name "SERVICE-NAME"`
Like this Picture

[Example about stop service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWuav.png)

[the result after stop service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEiAH.png)

4- If service doesn't stop try this command

```
Set-Service -Name "SERVICE-NAME" -Status stopped -force
```

**Another solution:**

1- Open powershell or CMD as administrator.

2- {{Path of service}} -k netsvcs

Comment: Hello, first solution doesn't work, and for second Unknown option '-k'.

Comment: Hello, open cmd as an administrator then try to use this comment 
taskkill /IM "[process-name]" /T /F